# create x number of child components based on input text field value in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to be able to create x number of child components based on what I type in an input text field in Angular 6. For example, if I type in 5, then 5 child components are created.

This is my parent component:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="circlecount">
<div id="rectangle">
   <app-circle *ngFor="let circle of circleArray; let i = index" 
      [index]="i"></app-circle>
</div>
```

This is my child component:

```
export class CircleComponent {
  circleArray;
  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() circlecount: number;

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.circleArray = Array(this.circlecount).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
  }  

}
```

I type in a number in the input field and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I put together to get this to work how you describe.

*shape.component.ts* (parent)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-shape',
    template: `<input type="text" class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="circleCount" (keyup)="changes()">
        <div id="rectangle">
        <app-circle *ngFor="let circle of circleArray; let i = index"
            [index]="i"></app-circle>
        </div>`,
    styles: ['']
})
export class ShapeComponent {
    circleCount = 0;
    circleArray = [];
    changes() {
        this.circleArray = new Array(+this.circleCount)
            .fill(0).map((x, i) => i);
    }
}
```

*circle.component.ts* (child)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-circle',
    template: `<div>Circle {{index}}</div>`,
    styles: ['']
})
export class CircleComponent {
    @Input() index: number;
    constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cant bind to a property in another component with ngModel. Bind the count to a property inside your parent component and then pass it to your child component via @Input

Comment: That's what I'm doing with [(ngModel)]="circlecount" and @Input() circlecount. I was able to pass circlecount to the child component but I can't use it in ngFor because it's a number. I tried creating an array with it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: In the code you provided u do are not passing circleCount to your child component. Anyways, try binding the input value change to some function, inside the function modify ur array property and of that array create the child components using NgFor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple. The lifecycle hook OnChanges is called when a databound property changes. For bindings with ngModel use (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)".

The markup:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="circlecount" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

The onModelChange event:

```
onChange(circlecount: number): void {
  this.circlecount = circlecount;
  this.circleArray = new Array(this.circlecount).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
}
```